# Qt5 Label Changed Text Shows Corrupted

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, visual-studio-2019

**App works nice in Qt Creator** but not in Visual Studio.

I try to learn C++ Qt5 GUI app in Visual Studio. Here is the basic app:

Click to button and change label text.

main.cpp

```
#include "Deneme.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QTextCodec>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("ISO 8859-9"));
    Deneme w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

header file:

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_Deneme.h"

class Deneme : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Deneme(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

private:
    Ui::DenemeClass ui;

private slots:
    void changeText();
};
```

cpp file:

```
#include "Deneme.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

Deneme::Deneme(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect(ui.pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(changeText()));
}

void Deneme::changeText() {
    ui.label->setText("Metin Değiştirildi!");
}
```

Label text is fine at the beginning. After button clicking, codec problem occured.

[image: initial label text]
[image: after clicked button]

I tried QTextCodec but didn't work:

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("ISO 8859-9"));
```

using:

- Qt5.15
- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2019
- MSVC 2019
- CMake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale( QTextCodec::codecForName( "UTF-8" ) );
ui.label->setText(QStringLiteral("Metin Değiştirildi!"));
```

Comment: It works thanks. Should I use QStringLiteral on every label at everytime? What does it do
?

Comment: You are welcome.
I think you should use QStringLiteral where your string is not utf-8. 
It will new a QString object from a Constant string.

Comment: `QStringLiteral` is just an optimization to create `QString` from a compile time constant char array. The important thing is the codec UTF-8. Your source file is probably stored in UTF-8, and thus, must be interpreted as UTF-8.